# Html Concatenate issue

Tags: php, html

I have the following code.

```
echo "<label><input type='checkbox' data-path=".".".$infostatus['status'].""." id='name' class='new1' value=".$infostatus['status']."/>".$infostatus['status']."<span></span></label> </li>";
```

It produces this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-path=".Deleted" without="" payment="" id="name" class="new1" value="Deleted">
```

Although I am trying to produce this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-path=".Deleted without payment" id="name" class="new1" value="Deleted without payment">
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here, I have tried just about everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First echo just the variable, and make sure it really is just "Deleted without payment". Once you have confirmed that, then you can wrap html around it.  You most likely have some quotes in your variable's value which would end your data-path field.

Comment: @Johan The correct way to deal with quotes and other special characters is to use `htmlspecialchars()` during output, like this: `echo "<label><input type='checkbox' data-path='".htmlspecialchars($infostatus['status'])}."'>";`.

Comment: That's assuming you want to deal with quotes by turning them into &quot; however there are times when you might want to keep quotes or replace them with something else.